# Checking Palindromes using BigInteger

Tags: java

I am currently working on an [/r/dailyprogramming challenge](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/38yy9s/20150608_challenge_218_easy_making_numbers/) to calculate how many steps it takes to turn a number into a palindromic number. e.g. 24 gets palindromic after 1 steps: 66 -> 24 + 42 = 66.

The program is working however, as one of the inputs is quite large, I have chosen to use BigInteger to solve the overflow problem I was having with regular integers.

Originally I was using code similar to that found on [LeetCode](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-reverse-integer/) to check if a value was a palindrome, which worked for input that didn't cause an overflow:

**Original Code Example used to check if Palindrome:**

```
public int reverse(int x) {

    //flag marks if x is negative
    boolean flag = false;

    if (x < 0) {
        x = 0 - x;
        flag = true;
    }

    int res = 0;
    int p = x;

    while (p > 0) {
        int mod = p % 10;
        p = p / 10;
        res = res * 10 + mod;
    }

    if (flag) {
        res = 0 - res;
    }

    return res;
}
```

I have since updated this code to account for my use of BigInteger's. However the updated code loops indefinitely, as the palindrome is never detected, so it continues to reverse and add - I have stepped through the program a few times now and I am unable to determine where I have incorrectly transposed from the original code I have written.

**Making_Numbers_Palindromic:**

```
public class Making_Numbers_Palindromic {

private BigInteger originalNumber;
private int count = 0;

public void run(BigInteger number) {
    assert (checkPositive(number));

    originalNumber = number;

    boolean flag = false;
    while (!flag) {
        if (checkPalindrome(number)) {
            System.out.printf("%d gets palindromic after" + 
                  "%d steps: %d", originalNumber, count, number);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        number = addReverse(number);
        count++;
    }
}

/**
 * @param number
 * @return BigInteger#signum returns 1 if the value is positive
 */
public boolean checkPositive(BigInteger number) {
    if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkPalindrome(BigInteger number) {
    if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) return false;

    BigInteger div = new BigInteger("1");

    while ((number.divide(div)).compareTo(BigInteger.TEN) >= 0) {
        div = div.multiply(BigInteger.TEN);
    }

    while (!number.equals(new BigInteger("0"))) {
        BigInteger len = number.divide(div);
        BigInteger revs = number.mod(BigInteger.TEN);

        if (!len.equals(revs)) return false;

        number = (number.mod(div)).divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        div = div.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    }
    return true;
}

public BigInteger addReverse(BigInteger number) {
    return number.add(reverse(number));
}

public BigInteger reverse(BigInteger number) {
    boolean flag = false;
    BigInteger reverse = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger numCopy = number;

    if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == -1) {
        flag = true;
    }

    while (numCopy.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
        BigInteger mod = numCopy.mod(BigInteger.TEN);
        numCopy = numCopy.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        reverse = (reverse.multiply(BigInteger.TEN)).add(mod);
    }

    if (flag) {
        reverse = BigInteger.ZERO.subtract(reverse);
    }
    return reverse;
  }
}
```

This is the first time I am using BigInteger and I have taken a look at the JavaDocs - but cannot see anything apparent that may be wrong with my usage of BigInteger#compare or BigInteger#equals

**The Main Method:**

```
public class Bootstrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Making_Numbers_Palindromic mnp = new Making_Numbers_Palindromic();

    if (args.length > 0) {
         mnp.run(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Usage: Palindromic Number");
    }
  }
}
```

I plan to make the Making_Numbers_Palindromic a private constructor so I can use it like a utility class, I just have not got around to it yet.

Thank-you

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be always 0 or 1 steps? 0 if number is a palindrome and 1 step if you have to, for example, divide it by itself to have 1 which is a palindrome as well? This problem is rather ...err...

Comment: For values such as 196196871, it becomes palindromic after 45 steps: 4478555400006996000045558744

Comment: You can reverse a `BigInteger` this way: `new BigInteger(new StringBuilder(number.toString()).reverse().toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's the only error, but in `checkPalindrome`

```
div = div.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
```

should be

```
div = div.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(100));
```

since after you compare the first and last digits of the number, you discard them, so the `div` of the next iterations should be 100 times smaller than the current `div`.

That said, even after you fix all the bugs, you will be doing double the work you should be doing, since if you reverse the number, you can use the reversed number to determine if the original is a palindrome (by comparing the original to the reversed number).

Comment: Hi Eran, Thank-you. I have changed that and it's now all working now. I wouldn't have picked up on that. Thanks again.